How to write the execution log of each model into a table DB?
I'm using DBT core and storing my models into a SQL Server DBT, and trying to find a way to write the execution log of each model into a table DB. The really basics, like DBT Project; DBt Model; Execution Start; Execution End; Status
Goal ultimately is to get an history and monitor the models execution from there.
I tried following https://github.com/brooklyn-data/dbt_artifacts but realized it is restricted to Databricks, Spark, Snowflake, Google BigQuery and Postgres - and uncertain if only cloud limited also?
Appreciate any hint :)

The dbt_artifacts package you mention now supports SQL Server.
